# Installation of heapster does not show metrics

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I'm trying to get additional `metrics` like `CPU` and `Memory` displayed on the Kubernetes Dashboard. Based on the different forums, it looks like you have to install `Heapter` under the `Kube System` namespace.
I installed `heapster`, however I'm not seeing any metrics on the dashboard and when I go visit the URL, it shows 404.
How do I show additional heapster metrics on Kubernetes Dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Heapter is deprecated in favor of metrics-server, it provides the same functionality you are looking for, i.e CPU and Memory usage in the dashboard

if you are using Kubernetes 1.8+ you can install it using

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.7/components.yaml
```

for more information check https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

Comment: I installed the metrics server as you suggested, but I still don't see the CPU and Memory Usage. I'm using dashboard version 2.0.3. How do I display it?

Comment: @VinhTran what is the output of kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system